# Parallel between Gad/Reuven approaching Moshe and 10 brothers approaching Yosef

Tags: vayigash, mattos

There are some parallels between two stories:

- In Miketz/Vayigash, 10 of the 12 brothers/tribes approach ("vayigash", Beresheit 42:18) Yosef (the Hebrew leader) as servants ("avadecha", Beresheit 42:10, etc.) with a request.
- In Matot, 2 of the 12 tribes approach ("vayigshu", Bamidbar 32:16) Moshe (the Hebrew leader) as servants ("avadecha", Bamidbar 32:4) with a request.

Have Chazal shared insights on parallels between these stories?

Comment: I haven't heard any, FWIW. The terms you pointed out are standard for people approaching a ruler with a request, so that is enough  of a parallel to explain the similarities.